How do I get the list of columns in local tables and tables that are datashares in Redshift?
Per aws documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_REDSHIFT_COLUMNS.html), SVV_REDSHIFT_COLUMNS is the table to use but it is extremely slow if I have to retrieve all columns for all tables.
How do I get the list of columns in local tables and tables that are datashares in Redshift?

Try information_schema.columns
